# How to move shader scripts in external files?

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, shader

I would like to know how could I move shaders which are actually included in my html to external files. In this way, I'll be able to include them in my gulp tasks. I took a look at how JavaScript shaders files are written but I don't understand very well.

For example with the Glow shader code below, how could I move it to an external file ?

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShaderGlow">
    uniform vec3 viewVector;
    uniform float c;
    uniform float p;
    varying float intensity;
    void main()
    {
        vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
        vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
        intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="fragmentShaderGlow">
    uniform vec3 glowColor;
    varying float intensity;
    void main()
    {
        vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
        gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You only need the shader code as a string, so any way that allows you to bring in a string from an external file could be used.

Comment: Can you show me an example please ?

Comment: I have edited the answer given by Shao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer suggesting joining an array of glsl lines is a pattern that can be encountered with three, but should probably be avoided in this use case.

It may be useful in some kind of a module, where it's sort of a "compiled" snapshot of a shader, not intended to be modified.

Otherwise the main downsides of this approach is lack of syntax highlighting and being verbose.

Nowadays most js code is transformed one way or the other. Shader code should be inlined like this.

```
const myShader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: require('./myVert.vs'),
  fragmentShader: require('./myFrag.vs'),
})
```

**edit**

myVert.vs:

```
//this is all nicely highlighted in sublime text for example
void main (){ 
    gl_Position = vec4( position.xy, 0., 1.); 
}
```

myVert.fs:

```
void main (){ 
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.,0.,0.,1.); 
}
```

myClass.js:

```
class myMaterial extends THREE.ShaderMaterial{
  constructor(){
    super({
      vertexShader: require('./myVert.vs'), 
      //^ becomes vertexShader: 'void main() {...}'
      ...
```

Comment: That method looks good, but it will increase the number of HTTP requests won't it ?  Shaders included in Javascript files were a good thing for me because i was able to minify/merge them and load only one Javascript for all my website. Also is the code in .vs files the same as the code in script tags or i need to adapt it ?

Comment: no this is to be used in conjunction with webpack or some other bundling tools. `.vs` is just a txt file. Once the bundling tool processes this, the `require(..)` would get replaced with the contents of the file. No additional requests are made, this is just inlined in your main bundle.

Comment: **please note** that shaders are nothing more than strings, the problem here is obtaining the string, sync, async, formatted or not. Three itself offers some features for dealing with these special strings such as the `#import ...` statement thats not part of GLSL. So it's kinda up to you to pick the most appropriate format. Plain old javascript cant do a multiline string, thats why you need to add `\n` or join the lines in an array. The next step are es6 strings where you can simply put write multiple lines.

Comment: You still wouldnt have highlighting, but at least its less verbose. The next step is keeping this in its own file, and then obtaining it some way. With bundlers, it's possible to "inline" it (turn the `require` statement into that string-formatted). If you want to load it remotely, it's just a text file, it can be fetched. If you're worreid about the number of requests, you can put multiple shaders in one file, then the problem is how to extract them. Again it's just strings, you can put something and regex it, or put it in a json file with shader names as keys, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It's quite difficult but I understand a bit more now.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer provided is simply taking GLSL code and turning each line into a string. Each string is a value in an array. The `join` call is concatenating all of the strings with a `\n` character to make the code easier to read when debugging. I've done it this way many times before, and is a legitimate solution to what you're trying to do.

But if you'd rather have external files with raw GLSL code, you can do that, too. Consider the two files:

- glow_vertex.glsl
- glow_fragment.glsl

These files contain the shader code which you would normally have in the script tags. You can use an [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to fetch the files, and use the returned text as your shader code.

```
var vertexShader = null;
var fragmentShader = null;

function shadersDone(){
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: { /* define your uniforms */},
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader
    });
}

function vertexDone(code){
    vertexShader = code;
    if(fragmentShader !== null){
        shadersDone();
    }
}

function fragmentDone(code){
    fragmentShader = code;
    if(vertexShader !== null){
        shadersDone();
    }
}

var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr1.open("GET", "/server/glow_vertex.glsl", true);
xhr2.open("GET", "/server/glow_fragment.glsl", true);

xhr1.responseType = "text";
xhr2.responseType = "text";

xhr1.onload = function(){
    if(xhr1.readyState === xhr1.DONE && xhr1.status === 200){
        vertexDone(xhr1.resultText);
    }
};
xhr2.onload = function(){
    if(xhr2.readyState === xhr2.DONE && xhr2.status === 200){
        fragmentDone(xhr2.resultText);
    }
};

xhr1.send(null);
xhr2.send(null);
```

Note that that's all asynchronous. Also, your server is going to need to be configured to send GLSL files as plain text.

**As long as we're talking about the modern web...**

There is also the option to `import` your shader code. **VERY BIG BUT** it's currently only supported in Chrome and Opera (although polyfills do exist). Microsoft Edge lists the functionality as "under consideration," and Firefox does not indent to implement it in its current state. So take what follows with a large grain of salt, and keep an eye on: http://caniuse.com/#search=import

In your HTML, and before the JavaScript which would use it...

```
<link id="vertexImport" rel="import" href="/server/glow_vertex.glsl" />
<link id="fragmentImport" rel="import" href="/server/glow_fragment.glsl" />
```

Then later in your JavaScript:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexImport").import.body.childNodes[0].data,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentImport").import.body.childNodes[0].data,
});
```

Again, this is asynchronous. You may need to add an `onload` handler for each link, so you don't attempt to access the code before it's loaded.

Comment: It shouldn't be a legitimate solution. Its the second half of 2017, `(glsl | vert 
| frag | fs | vs )` should all be extensions that you can either `require` and inline in your code, or do an xhr request. The second approach should be depreciated.

Comment: @pailhead You may find my addition interesting, if a little unuseful for cross-browser.

Comment: Very interesting, the negative point for me is that it needs a server configuration, and it's a little bit more heavy to manage :/

Comment: nah, the modern way would be an example with webpack :D

Answer (score 0):

You can move the shader code into a separate JS file and include that file after three.js.
Here is one example from https://github.com/timoxley/threejs/blob/master/examples/js/shaders/ColorifyShader.js

```
/**
 * @author alteredq / http://alteredqualia.com/
 *
 * Colorify shader
 */

THREE.ColorifyShader = {

    uniforms: {

        "tDiffuse": { type: "t", value: null },
        "color":    { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) }

    },

    vertexShader: [

        "varying vec2 vUv;",

        "void main() {",

            "vUv = uv;",
            "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",

        "}"

    ].join("\n"),

    fragmentShader: [

        "uniform vec3 color;",
        "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",

        "varying vec2 vUv;",

        "void main() {",

            "vec4 texel = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );",

            "vec3 luma = vec3( 0.299, 0.587, 0.114 );",
            "float v = dot( texel.xyz, luma );",

            "gl_FragColor = vec4( v * color, texel.w );",

        "}"

    ].join("\n")

};
```

With the above you would create our material like this:

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms : THREE.ColorifyShader.uniforms,
  vertexShader : THREE.ColorifyShader.vertexShader,
  fragmentShader : THREE.ColorifyShader.fragmentShader
});
```

ofcourse you don't need to call the object `THREE.ColorifyShader`, you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: not sure why this got a down vote, seems like a reasonable answer to me and it is how I have sometimes done it in the past.

Comment: I already know that i can move the shader code into a separate JS file and include that file after three.js, that wasn't my question.

Comment: I'd like to know the method to convert one syntaxe to the other, the code seems to be written in two different ways.

Comment: This has many problems, it's verbose, prone to error, it doesn't give you syntax highlighting. Javascript nowadays is transformed, this should just be `require('myShader.vs')`.